# MongoDB, создание объекта БД по значению переменной

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backend

В БД есть объект, в котором потенциально может быть до полутора сотен объектов. Хотелось бы, чтобы каждый объект был именованным, как здесь:

[image: BD]

Для данного примера жестко прописаны названия объектов в коде:

[image: Code]

Как сделать так, чтобы именованный объект создавался по значению, которое находится в переменной? Код вроде `object.${id}: {}` и `object[id]: {}` не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На зарубежном форуме по MongoDB подсказали решение:

```
[`roles.${role}.wins`]: wins,
[`roles.${role}.matches`]: matches,
```